# Use the Bluetooth API in JavaScript to connect to media output devices?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth

I am having some difficulties with connecting a Bluetooth audio output device with JavaScript's `navigator.bluetooth` class. Help is appreciated.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
function opendevicemenu() {
    if ('bluetooth' in navigator) {
        navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ acceptAllDevices: true }).then(devices => {
            console.log(devices)
            devices.gatt.connect()
        })
    }
}
```

I am also using Chrome.

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: @user18309290 when i go into the Chrome console/inspect element, I try and emit the same function. But, the output is undefined.

Comment: Could you be more specific, output of what?

Comment: navigator.bluetooth

Comment: That means either your browser doesn't support bluetooth or the device doesn't have it. Is bluetooth turned on?

Comment: yep. if it wasn't, it would say in the prompt